# rvest Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) : Could not resolve host: google.com; Host not found

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to use rvest package (downloaded from CRAN) to scrape certain contents from website but got an error:

```
library(rvest)    
html("http://google.com")
```

Here's the result:

Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Could not resolve host: google.com; Host not found

I tried Sys.setenv(http_proxy = "webproxy:port") or set ./Renviron files and a few other tricks I found on stackoverflow but none works.

Comment: Well, are you behind a proxy? Can you access the internet from that machine (did you run `install.packages()` on that machine successfully)? Have you tried other websites? Tell us exactly what you've already tried so we know what to rule out (what are the "few other tricks").

Comment: yes, "download.file()" works, "install.packages()" works as well. httr / XML / rvest, none of these work unfortunately

Comment: I encountered the same situation this morning when sourcing a script that includes calls to `html()` and some subsequent downloading. The process failed at the first call to `html()` with the error you describe. I tried navigating directly to the web page in question, and my browser threw the same error. I tried closing the browser and rerunning the process, but that didn't work. Then I rebooted the whole system, opened R, and tried again. This time it worked. Firewall issue, maybe?